# Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation using laravel / ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel

I'm trying to when I switch a checkbox change the column `paye` in the database to 1 and change the column `date_paiement`.

So I'm using the following code :

I have the following modal form :

```
<div class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" id="formModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <h5 class="modal-title">Modal title</h5>
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                <form id="date_payement" method="post" action="projets"   enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    {{ csrf_field() }}
                    <input type="hidden" id="id_hidden" name="id_projet" />
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label for="casting_date_naissancee">Date de payement</label>
                        <div class="input-group date">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="date_paiement" name="date_paiement">
                                <span class="input-group-text input-group-append input-group-addon" id="spanEstPaymentDate">
                                    <i class="simple-icon-calendar"></i>
                                </span> 
                            </div>
                       </div>
                       <div class="form-group" align="center">
                           <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" />
                           <input type="hidden" name="hidden_id" id="hidden_id" />
                           <input type="submit" name="action_button" id="action_button" class="btn btn-warning" value="Enregistrer" />
                        </div>
                        <div class=" col-md-6">
                            <span id="form_result"></span>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

And the following script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(document).on('change', '.selectRow1', function() {
        $('.modal-title').text("Saisir la date de paiement");
        $('#action_button').val("Enregistrer");
        $('#action').val("Enregistrer");
        $('#formModal').modal('show');
        var paye = $(this).prop('checked') == true ? 1 : 0;
        console.log(paye);
        var id = $(this).attr('id');
        console.log(id);
        $('#date_payement').on('submit', function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            if ($('#action').val() == 'Enregistrer') {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    dataType: "json",
                    url: 'projets/paiement',
                    data: {
                        'paye': paye,
                        'id_projet': id,
                        'date_paiement': new FormData(this)
                    },
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data)
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
});
```

And this is the **controller**:

```
public function paiement(Request $request) {
    $request->validate(['paye'=>'required','id_projet'=>'required','date_paiement'=>'required']);
    $projet = Projet::find($request->id_projet);
    if($projet){
        $projet->paye = $request->paye;
        $projet->date_paiement = $request->date_paiement;
        $projet->save();
        return response()->json(['success'=>'Status change successfully.']);
    }
    return response()->json(['failed'=>'Status change failed.'],422);
}
```

So I want when I switch the selected box I should get the paye if it is 0 or 1 and show the modal form to write the date_paiement and change into the database the two columns paye and date_paiement.

But with this code I get the following error :

```
Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation
```

If you have any idea, please help

Comment: Share the whole error... in which line is that happening ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using FormData incorrectly, you have to pass that as the data, not part of it.
Also, you have to specify `processData: false,` to prevent `$.ajax` from trying to convert formdata to string and `contentType: false,` to prevent `$.ajax` from trying set an incorrect content type.

```
$('#date_payement').on('submit', function(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if ($('#action').val() == 'Enregistrer') {
    var data = new FormData(this);
    data.append('paye', paye);
    data.append('id_projet', id);
    $.ajax({
      type: "post",
      dataType: "json",
      url: 'projets/paiement',
      data: data,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(data) {
        console.log(data)
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: thak you for your answer , I tried that but I'm getting this error : `Uncaught TypeError: Failed to construct 'FormData': Please use the 'new' operator, this DOM object constructor cannot be called as a function.`

Comment: I just edit `var data = FormData(this);` to `var data =new FormData(this);` and it works